# Teamcity upgrade from 9.16 to 10

Tags: teamcity, upgrade, teamcity-9.0

I want to upgrade Teamcity 9.16 to 10. I want to proceed with manual back-up and then restore it . I am using external database - mysql . i want to upgrade database as well. How should i proceed with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeamCity documentation states that

> Backups created with TeamCity 6.0+ can be restored using the same or
>   more recent TeamCity versions

so you should be able to create a backup in TC9 and then restore it in TC10.

The simplest way to create a backup is to navigate to the `Administration | Backup` section in the server UI to specify some parameters and run the backup, as described [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Creating+Backup+from+TeamCity+Web+UI).

The other options are

- backup via the `maintainDB` command-line tool — it is basically the same option, as backup via the UI
- manual backup

which are described on the corresponding [page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/TeamCity+Data+Backup) of the TC documentation.

Restoring data from backup is performed using the `maintainDB` tool, basically the steps for your case are:

- install new TeamCity (but do not start the server)
- create a new empty Data Directory
- create and configure an empty database
- configure a temporary database.properties file
- place the database drivers into the `lib/jdbc` in new data directory
- use the `maintainDB` utility located in the `<TeamCity Home>/bin` to run `restore` command:

  ```
  maintainDB.[cmd|sh] restore -A <absolute path to the Data Directory> -F <path to the TeamCity backup file> -T <absolute path to the database.properties file>
  ```
- If the process completes successfully, copy over
  /system/artifacts from the old directory

More details could be found on the corresponding [page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Restoring+TeamCity+Data+from+Backup).